# Settings to revert when activating Windows 7 after the 30-day grace period?

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

When activating Windows 7 after the 30-day grace period (i.e. after the screen turns black), which settings do you have to revert manually?

So far I have only noticed the background image and the registry key for using an OEM image on the logon screen. But I fear that some other -performance or security relared- settings were also changed.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the system state (i.e. registry values) after the 30-day grace period ran out to the system state after activating the system and to the system state of a backup shortly before the end of the grace period, it seems nothing important changes with regards to security, energy or performance settings.

The only things that happen are:

- a different desktop theme is activated every hour (black background with Windows version; changing the theme also sets OEMBackground=0 if no appropriate group policy is set)
- Windows updates are deactivated other than some important ones
- popup messages start to appear frequently, stating that the copy might not be genuine and should be activated

I also read that there is a pause during system start and that the small Windows programs no longer work / can no longer be downloaded, but I could not verify either of this.